# postgresql array query (cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality)

Tags: json, postgresql

```
select * from temp10

k    v
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
a   {a,b}
a   {c}
b   {d,e}
b   {f}

to

k    v
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
a   {a,b,c}
b   {d,e,f}
```

I want these results.

my try ↓

```
select k,json_agg(v) 
from temp10
group by k 
=
k    v
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
a   [["a","b"],  ["c"]]
b   [["d","e"],  ["f"]]


select k,array_agg(v) 
from temp10
group by k 
=
SQL Error [2202E]: ERROR: cannot accumulate arrays of different dimensionality
```

help me

Is there anything lacking in my explanation?
Is there anything lacking in my explanation?
Is there anything lacking in my explanation?

Comment: instead of direct aggregate on array, you should aggregate on item. so you need flatten(unnest) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten v and aggregate as a new array -

```sql
SELECT k, ARRAY_AGG(v) FROM 
(SELECT k,UNNEST(v) v FROM temp10) test
GROUP BY k
```